# is there a way to have a Subject and Observable under the same variable

Tags: typescript, rxjs

currently I've got a code like this:

```
const exampleSubject = new Subject<any>();
const example$ = exampleSubject.pipe(...);
// later emit some data to that subject and do things with observable, like subscribtion
```

and it's working fine, but is there a way to have both `Subject` and `Observable` under the same variable/property and transforming the data at the same time, eg:

```
const example$ = (a subject constructor).pipe(...);
// later execute example$.emit(...), example$.subscribe(...), etc.
```

as you may notice the `pipe` operator always returns `Observable<T>` instance so that's the problem, but maybe I'm missing some functionality?

I'd rather to avoid creating little monsters like:

```
let subscriber: Subscriber<any>;
const example$ = (new Observable<any>((sub) => { subscriber = sub; })).pipe(...);
// later calling subscriber.next(...), subscriber.complete(...), etc.
```

so is there a way to have a Subject and Observable (with pipes or other way of using operators) under the same variable and still emit the data from the outside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. `Subject` is a subtype of `Observable`. `pipe` works with `Observable`, so, of course, it works with `Subject` too, but you get an `Observable`, not a `Subject` as the result of calling that function.

There's no point in 'feeding' data to the observables result of chaining operators via `pipe`, as, by calling such operators, you're saying that you want the result `Observable` to be an stream of transformed values coming from the origin `Observable` data stream. I mean, you can use `map` to alter a stream of numbers and get their squares. What would be the purpose of 'feeding' data to the result observable?

```
const subject = new Subject<number>();
const squares$ = subject.pipe(map(item => item*item));
squares$.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
squares$.next(2); // we get 4 in the console.
```

You can achieve this with functions that act as operators to your data:

```
const square = (value: number) => value*value;
const subject = new Subject<number>();
subject.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
subject.next(square(2)); // we get 4 in the console.
```

Of course, you could simplify this by creating a new subclass from `Subject` that accepts functions that transforms values:

```
const transSubject = new TransSubject<number>(value => value*value);
transSubject.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
transSubject.next(2); // we get 4 in the console.
```

Basically, such a class would store an array of transformation functions in its constructor, and then you override the `next` method so that you apply the transform functions in order before passing the resulting value to the superclass `next` method.

Of course, this has still a problem, which is that once you define the data type of your `TransSubject`, you cannot return a different type. Of course you could define a `TransSubject<T, K>` class, so that `next` is `next(value: K)` and `subscribe` would be defined as `subscribe({next: (value: T) => any, complete: ...})`, but it would be very complicated. You should make sure that the combination of functions in the constructor is of type `K => T`. You could have something like:

```
const sbj = new TransSubject<string, number>((value: number) => value*value, (value: number) => value.toString());
```

In this case we'd have `number => number` and `number => string` so, combining, `number => string`, with matches the type parameters.

However, as I said, it would be easier to do this with simple functions and using a normal observable. You could even make a closure to simplify it:

```
const subject = new Subject<string>();
const next = (value: number) => subject.next((value * value).toString());
subject.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
next(1); // logs '1'
next(2); // logs '4'
```

But, of course, again you would need two variables/properties